# How can I save Entity's foreign key to another table? Springboot

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, controller

I have a endpoint that choose randomly EmployeeOfMonth. I have a EmployeeOfMonth table with ManyToOne relationship. I can choose randomly but I want to save it selected employee to EmployeeOfMonth table. I couldn't figure it out. How can I do that ? Thanks to all

Employee :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="national_id")
    private String nationalId;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String surname;

    private Integer salary;

    @Column(name="start_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date startDate;

    private String office;

    private String department;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "employee",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<EmployeeOfMonths> employeeOfMonths;

}
```

EmployeeOfMonths :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class EmployeeOfMonths{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Employee employee;
}
```

EmployeeRepository :

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository <Employee,Integer>, QueryByExampleExecutor<Employee> { }
```

EmployeeOfMonthRepository :

```
public interface EmployeeOfMonthsRepository extends JpaRepository <EmployeeOfMonths,Integer> {
}
```

EmployeeServiceImp :

```
  @Override
    public EmployeeDTO selectEmployee(Employee employee) {
        List<Employee> all = employeeRepository.findAll();
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        Employee random = all.get(randomizer.nextInt(all.size()));
   

        return EmployeeMapper.toDto(random);
        }
```

Controller :

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?", zone = "Europe/Istanbul")
    @GetMapping(path="/month")
    public EmployeeDTO selectEmployee(Employee employee){
        return employeeService.selectEmployee(employee);
    }
```

Comment: When I try it I get this error : Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.example.macademiaproject.model.EmployeeOfMonths'

Comment: You are using the same table name for both tables, do you have the same in the code?

Comment: Yeah it's a mistake. Just corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of `EmployeeOfMonths` and save it using the respective repository.

Simplified, it should look smth like this:

```
public EmployeeDTO selectEmployee(Employee employee) {
        List<Employee> all = employeeRepository.findAll();
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        Employee random = all.get(randomizer.nextInt(all.size()));
   

        employeeOfMonthsRepository.save(new EmployeeOfMonths(random));       
 
        return EmployeeMapper.toDto(random);
}
```

Comment: I try this :employeeOfMonthsRepository.save((EmployeeMapper.toDto(random))); but it gave me error :  Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound.

Comment: You cannot save an EmployeeDTO, the object you save must be an entity of type EmployeeOfMonths. DTO is not an entity. You are basically trying to save a “user” in table “books”

Comment: I want to save foreign key of Employee to EmployeeOfMonths. How can I do that then ?. Can you show me ?

Comment: I updated the answer. You cannot "save the foreign key". Foreign key is an abstraction. But if you save the "EmployeeOfMonths" as I mentioned, the record will reference the entity in "employee" table